# How do I call a service with HTTP Basic using Postman?

Tags: curl, basic-authentication, postman, stormpath

I'm using curl to make a request:

```
curl -u NL91IOC2RWCM31G1ESWYX:SvCuj0tFQjmclZDFQzdMqfrGZ5Qw5jfKM8 \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/649j4AnLkUMezhYTl61
```

How do I make this same request using Postman?

Comment: FYI: Your key and secret are visible here. Make sure you disable this pair and generate a new key and secret immediately.

Comment: I did not post my actual key and secret :). @Nate

Comment: Ah, good. Just checking :)

Answer (score 3):

`curl -u key:secret` sends a request with HTTP Basic authentication. It's easy to do this in Postman:

1. Enter the endpoint URL in the address field.

[image: Enter URL]

2. Switch to the **Authorization** tab and choose Basic Auth. Enter the key as Username and the secret as Password. Click **Update Request** to generate the proper Authorization header for the request.

[image: Authorization]

3. Switch to the **Headers** tab and add the Accept header.

[image: Headers]

4. Press **Send**.