# How to simulate request using POSTMAN that can populate remoteUser of HttpServletRequest with different values?

Tags: java, postman

I am now testing a RESTFul API using **POSTMAN**. The API is developed using Java and Spring-Boot.

Within the REST Controller, it validates the request by checking the remote user like below:

```
boolean validate(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (request.getRemoteUser() == "Test123") {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So how can I generate a request using POSTMAN to populate the `remoteUser` of the `HttpServletRequest` object?

Comment: you need to add basic Authentication header in your postman request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call a service with HTTP Basic using Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875432/how-do-i-call-a-service-with-http-basic-using-postman)

Comment: I have set authorization to "basic-auth" but the getRemoteUser() method of  HttpServletRequest object still returns null.

Comment: Hi @Kelvin Are you using spring-security or any other forms of security implementation? If you are using spring-security, you may have to add a custom filter. See [Spring security removes RemoteUser from httpServletRequest
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49693007/spring-security-removes-remoteuser-from-httpservletrequest)